# Non-generated script with SetupTools/Distribute in setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, easy-install

I'm trying to get a non-generated script when I run `setup.py install` for a Python Package that I am building.

I have read the distutils documentation but couldn't find clear examples on how to accomplish this.

Mercurial does this in some part by importing the `install_scripts` :

```
from distutils.command.install_scripts import install_scripts
```

And then goes on to replace some things within their `hg` script. This `hg` executable ends up being used overriding the default behavior of using something like this:

```
#!/Users/alfredo/python/foo/bin/python  
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'foo==0.0.1','foo'
__requires__ = 'foo==0.0.1'
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.run_script('foo==0.0.1', 'foo')
```

I am trying *not* to end up using pkg_resources importing my `foo` package, but rather
end up with a script I am using. I'm aware why this is auto-generated and still want to 
go the other route.

This is a copy of the base setup.py that I am using:

```
import distribute_setup
distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
from setuptools import setup

tests_require = ['pytest']

setup(
name = "foo",
version = "0.0.1",
packages = ['_foo'],

scripts = ['foo'],
zip_safe = False,
package_data = {'': ['distribute_setup.py']},
author = "Alfredo Deza",
author_email = "alfredodeza [at] gmail [dot] com",
description = "",
long_description = """\
Foo
""",
classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
  ],

license = "MIT",
keywords = "",
url = "",   

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of digging around... it turns out that Mercurial is not doing anything *special*.

Even though their `setup.py` does a lot of things it actually does not do **anything** to interfere with installing a script correctly without pkg_resources linking to it.

What is the difference then?

The difference is that I am using Distribute, and the way it works it overrides the `setup` module with its own (instead of setuptools) and thus it has its own different behavior for installation.

In my case, that *different* way of installing scripts, means that a script `foo` will get copied over to the egg location and linked through a `foo` script that imports pkg_resources and links to that version.

This is **not** what I want and I couldn't find **any** Distribute documentation on it. However, it is clear they do so to provide a way of uninstallation later on.

So beware! If you do want to go my path, you will have issues if you want to uninstall stuff.

Until Distribute doesn't provide a way for me to customize what to copy in my scripts I will have to switch back to regular `setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, using the `--single-version-externally-managed` argument [when installing](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#install-command) should do as you like.

Comment: That is a flag to setup.py but I'm aiming at handling this within setup.py instead

Comment: Don't. Sysadmins and packagers will kill you.

Comment: Mercurial handles this flawlessly. If it works as perfect for them, why not? I absolutely despise the way that pkg_resources handles things